# How to avoid component mounting in react native when application is active from background?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

In my case, there is screen which has multiple fields. On iPhone when someone clicks on the Home button, after filling some fields and again comes back to application. The screen component gets remounted and all the data is lost.
How to avoid this data loss? User should be back to the same state he left from.

Answer (score 0):

use  shouldComponentUpdate() to prevent unwanted renders.